# Global variable in rails similar to the one in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, global-variables

In rails, if I am using devise for a table "users", it creates a global variable current_user which is used throughout the code. I want to add a similar global variable (current_auth_user) without touching the devise code. Whats the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application controller you can just add a helper method

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_auth_user

  protected

  def current_auth_user
    return whatever
  end

end
```